# Magento addField and put value into $_POST

Tags: magento, post, request

Is there any specific conditions to add fields to the order create page, for example some fields to shipping method, and when you fill values into these field, values were transfered into array `$_POST`?

I added some fields and tried to create order in admin area. When I filled all added fields and changed shipping method to let ajax add values to array `$_POST`, I saw that not all field values were added to `$_POST`.

For example:

```
<input name="name[aaa]" ....
<select name="name[bbb][]"...
 <option>....
<input name="name[ccc]"....
```

In `$_POST` I only see: (I set breakpoint on first row of index.php)

```
->name
  ->aaa = ...
  ->ccc = ...
```

But I don't see value of `name="name[bbb][]"`

On the frontend I have no problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem.
to put data into request just need to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
order.setShippingMethod = function (method) {
    var data = {};
    data['...'] = $('...').value;
....
    this.loadArea(['shipping_method', 'totals', 'billing_method', 'message'], true, data);
}
</script>
```